# Does anyone have a List of hive error codes?

Tags: hadoop, hive, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn

Does anyone have the list of hive error codes?

For example, if we get a table not found error in hive, the value of "echo $?" will be 17.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/master/common/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/ErrorMsg.java you'll see most of the error codes.

[image]

Although in order to map these to an exit code, you'd probably have to walk through the CLI code to trace that.